# Google Chrome DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to solve this below warning messages from my google chrome console, but can't solve it. is there any way to solve this.

Already tried with Disabled options from `setting` `->` `Enable JavaScript source maps`, & `Enable CSS source maps` but still facing the same warnings.

Please provide any better suggestions.

[image]

[image: setting] [image: Enable JavaScript source maps]

Comment: I used to get this error because of an extension I added. So you can try disabling some extensions that might be causing these errors.

Comment: Also tried with disabled the options of `Selected context only` from the `Console's Setting menu`, but still getting the same warnings.